# How do these magic methods allow operations with attribute that is not defined in Yii? ( PHP )

Tags: php, class, variables, yii

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass extends CActiveRecord {

  public function getSelectedIds()
  {
    return '';
  }

  public function setSelectedIds($value)
  {
    $this->selectedIds = $value;
  }

}
```

This kind of produces weird results:

```
$object = new MyClass();
$object->selectedIds = 'test';
//Line below shows 'test'
echo $object->selectedIds;
//line below show ''
echo $object->getSelectedIds();
```

Now my question is why doesn't it break/show some error? Why `$this->selectedIds = $value;` works within the method even though selectedIds is not defined within the class?

**Edit:**

Basically I understand that `$object->selectedIds = 'xx'` resolves to `setSelectedIds($xx)`.

But what does `$this->selectedIds == 'xx'` resolve to? To itself? And if so why not loop into infinity?

And why `$object->selectedIds != $object->getSelectedIds()` if `$object->selectedIds` should resolve to `$object->getSelectedIds()`...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's so magic about this behaviour... You're setting an attribute value and when reading it you get the same value back... When you call an unrelated function you get the function's return value... What exactly did you expect to happen...?

Comment: Please see Edit section

Comment: Add some `echo __METHOD__` to your two methods to see whether they're actually being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why `$this->selectedIds = $value;` works within the method even though selectedIds is not defined within the class?

You can freely add properties to objects at any time without previously having declared them.

```
$o = new stdClass;
$o->foo = 'bar';
```

They'll be created as plain `public` properties. It's possible that `setSelectedIds` isn't even called and you're just setting the property on the object straight (don't know if or how `CActiveRecord` defines `__set`).

Comment: OK I think I got it... If set was never called then property does not exist so asking for its value will always return whatever 'get' function returns. However if 'set' was called at least once, then property is created and henceforth $object->selectedIds returns value of that property, while getSelectedIds() will always return whatever that method returns.

Comment: Yes, `__get` will only be invoked for properties which are *not accessible*. If you create the property publicly, then it is accessible and no magic `__get` will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Because:

```
$object->selectedIds
```

automatically resolves as function call, either `getSelectedIds` or `setSelectedIds`.

This concept is called ***Virtual Attributes*** and is achieved via custom implementation of `__get` and `__set`. Have a look at: [Yii 1.1: Understanding Virtual Attributes and get/set methods](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/#hh0)